# ServiceStack webservice working in ie9 or ie10 using localhost as address but not with ip address as the address

Tags: internet-explorer, servicestack

I've run into an issue where chrome and opera work fine for this but there is a form that is throwing fits in internet explorer 9 and 10 when I use either the hostname or the ip rather than localhost in the url.  There is another form object that works for everything that is only a text box and a submit button.

The form I'm having trouble with has text fields, a select list, a dropdown, and a check box.

I do not receive the event from the submit button in internet explorer, but I do in the other browsers.

The error:

```
Error Code:
RequestBindingException: Unable to bind request
Stack:
at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.GetRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IRestPath restPath) at ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.RestHandler.ProcessRequest(IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes, String operationName)
```

The code :

```
<form style="width:inherit; margin:4px" action="/search" method="post"><label style="color: white;">Quick Search</label><br>
                <label style="color: white;">Colors:</label>
                <br/>
                @*<input style="width:100px;" name="Colors" type="text"><br>*@
                <select name="Colors" style="height:200px; width:100px;" multiple>
                    @{
                        @:<option value ="Any">Any</option>
                        foreach(Color colors in Repositories.TypeGetters.GetAllColors())
                        {
                            @:<option value ="@colors.Description">@colors.Description</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select><br>
                <input style="color: white; font-size:small" type="checkbox" name="PredominantColor" value="1" />
                <label style="color: white;">Predominant Color?</label><br />
                <label style="color: white; width:30px">D1</label><label style="color: white; width:30px">xD2:</label><br />
                <input style="width:30px" name="D1" type="text"><label style="color: white;">mm. X </label>
                <input style="width:30px" name="D2" type="text"><label style="color: white;">mm.</label><br />
                <label style="color: white;">Number of Layers:</label><br>
                <input style="width:30px" name="LayersCount" type="text"><br>
                <label style="color: white; width:100px">Flexibility:</label><br/>
                <select style="width:100px" name="Flexibility">
                    @{
                        @:<option value ="Any">Any</option>
                        foreach(FlexibilityType flex in Repositories.TypeGetters.GetAllFlexTypes())
                        {
                            @:<option value ="@flex.Description">@flex.Description</option>
                        }
                    }
                </select> <br />
                <button name="SearchType" type="submit" value="2" style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">Submit</button><br />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As things go I spent all day on this and I figure out a solution.  Instead of using a

`<button name="SearchType" type="submit" value="2" style="float:right; margin-right:20px;">Submit</button>`

tag I used

`<input name="SearchType" type="submit" value="2" style="float:right; margin-right:20px;" /><br />`

and it fixed the issue.

I cannot understand or explain why internet explorer did not work the other way around, but this works.  I"m going to guess that this is due to IE's html5 support issues.